# Adiabatic CMOS circuits in low power design

Tags: mosfet, low-power, cmos

There are several techniques to reduce dynamic power consumption in low power design, but I could not understand the basic concepts of Adiabatic circuits and how will it reduce the dynamic power consumption in the low power design. Any help is appreciated

Comment: which part ? Unlike traditional CMOS circuits, which dissipate energy during switching, adiabatic circuits reduce dissipation by following two key rules:

    Never turn on a transistor when there is a voltage potential between the source and drain.
    Never turn off a transistor when current is flowing through it.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely correct. but I could not understand how those two rules reduce power dissipation. Can you explain in detail

Answer (score 1):

They use Transmission gates and bi-phase triangular clocks to reduce Ic=CdV/dt and stagger the clocks. But uses twice the real-estate of CMOS.

The basic buffer element consists of two
sets of transmission gates. Φ1 and Φ0 are both trapezoidal clocks but Φ1 is a
quarter cycle behind Φ0.

Initially all the nodes are at 0. As the input gradually
raises to 1 (if it is 1) or stays at 0, Φ0 transitions to 1.

On the next step, Φ1 transitions to 1 which sets the output to 1 if the input was one and otherwise leaves it at 0 which in itself reduces the power dissipation because no charge passes through the transistor.

On the third step Φ0 transitions back to 0 reseting the input to 0.

Finally Φ1 transitions back to 0 and the output is restored to 0 by the following gate in order to accommodate for full pipelining and thus the circuit is ready to process a new input.